# How to turn off effects on anchored object that are nested from textbox?

Tags: adobe-indesign, effects, drop-shadow

Adobe Indesign CS6. Take a look on this image:
[image: anchored object nested shadow]

How to remove shadow under blue shape?
I can't clear effects on this object: [image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can because it's a text frame with the effect applied to it. You could create a yellow box with drop shadow, add a text frame above the yellow box, then anchor the blue to that text frame. I think because you're styling the text frame you are restricted to all anchors also being styled. (now deleted answer was for groups, not anchored objects).

Comment: I need automatic height mode enabled on yellow box, so one more shadowed object below the textbox can't solve this problem.

Comment: Then I suspect you may need to rethink the design, or at least the anchor.

Comment: I'm trying to make footer of the website in this way. The footer must be at the end of the text tread. Is there any solution (except anchored obj.) on how to put an object at the end of the block with altering height?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Indesign for web site layouts. I can't help with that.

Comment: If you make a 3rd text box and then anchor both objects in that, then it is possible to get the one item to follow (to some limited degree) the auto-height. Perhaps with runaround (text wrap) and proper offsets you can get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drop shadow appears on both objects because the anchored object *is* part of the main text frame object.

Instead of applying the effect to the text frame object, apply it to the fill. Since the fill is contained in the text frame object, and not the anchored object, the shadow will appear only behind the text frame. (Note that this only works if the text frame actually has a fill, but a Paper fill works just as well as a color or gradient.)

Comment: Thanks! That works. To add effect I select a textbox → open Effects panel → double-clicked on ‘Fill: Normal 100%’ → apply a shadow. Voila!